Impact of Applying a Function to Observations from Random Variables
I have a sequence of observations from random variables, which can be:

IID (Independent and Identically Distributed), or
Non-IID (Independent but not Identically Distributed).

If I apply the same function to all observations in the sequence, I want to understand how it affects the following statistical properties:

Independence and Dependence: Is the independence or dependence structure preserved?

Identical Distribution (IID): If the original sequence is IID, does applying the same function preserve this property? Can a non-IID sequence become IID?

LLN and CLT: If the original sequence satisfies the Weak or Strong Law of Large Numbers (LLN) or the Central Limit Theorem (CLT), will these still hold after applying the same function?


Additionally, how do the answers change if I apply different functions to the observations instead of the same function?
If possible, please provide references or resources for further reading on this topic.

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent then $f(X)$ and $g(Y)$ are independent.  If $X$ and $Y$ are identically distributed then $f(X)$ and $f(Y)$ are identically distributed.

The duplicate answers #1.  #2 is a direct result of any definition of a distribution.  That leaves #3, but I would encourage you to look for counterexamples.  If $X$ is a random variable with finite variance (as required by the CLT), consider any measurable function $f$ for which $f(X)$ has infinite variance, for instance.

Thanks @whuber could you plz elaborate on #2? Can a non-IID sequence become IID?

That's an interesting question that I overlooked amid all your other questions.  (That's why we request that posts focus on a single question!)  But the answer to that is yes.  One way to see it is to work backwards.  Take two iid non-negative random variables $Y_1,$ $Y_2$ and multiply them by the same Rademacher variable $U$ to obtain a dependent sequence $X_i=UY_i.$ The absolute value function converts the non-iid $X_i$ back into the iid $Y_i.$
